# Need for multi-threading in Systemverilog using fork-join

Tags: system-verilog

In most text books advocating layered testbench designs, it is recommended that different layers/block run in parallel. I'm currently unable to figure out the reason why is it so. Why cannot we follow the following sequence.

```
repeat for 1000 tests
    generate a transaction
    drive the transaction on the DUT
    monitor the transaction on the DUT
    compare output with a reference
```

Instead, what is recommended is that all four blocks generator, driver, monitor and scoreboard/checker should run in parallel. My confusion is that why do we avoid the above mentioned sequential behavior in which we go through tests one test case at a time and prefer different blocks running in parallel.

Some texts say that it is because that is how things are done in hardware, i.e. everything runs in parallel. However, the layered testbench is not needed to model any synthesizable hardware. So, why do we have to restrict our verification enivornment/testbench to follow these hardware-like behavior.

A sample block diagram that I'm referring to is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have a fifo which you want to test. Your driver pushes data into it, and the monitor checks the other end. The data gets pushed when it is available and till the fifo is full, the consumer on the other end reads data when it can. So, the pipe gets sometimes full, sometimes empty.

When the fifo is full, the driver must stop. The monitor works always, but its values do not change at the same frequency as the stimuli and it is delayed due to the fifo depth.

In your example, when the fifo is full, the stopped driver will block the whole loop, so the monitor will not work either. Of course, you can come up with some conditional statements which will bypass stopped driver. But you will need to run the monitor and the scoreboard every time, even if the data is not changing.

With more complicated designs with multiple fifos, pipelines, delays, clock frequencies, etc., your loop will become so complicated that it would be difficult if not impossible to manage.

The problem is that in the simple programming it is not possible to express block/wait conditions for statement without blocking the whole loop. It is much easier to do with parallel threads.

The general approach is to run driver and monitor in separate simulation threads. Monitor in this case waits for the data to appear and does not block the driver. The driver pushes data when it is available and can be blocked by fifo full or if there is nothing to drive. It does not block the monitor.

With a single monitor, you can probably pack the scoreboard in the same thread with the monitor, but with multiple monitors it will be problematic, in particular when all monitors run in separate threads.  So, the scoreboard should run as a separate thread as well.

Comment: Perfect answer. Just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different concepts. The layered approach is a software concept that helps manage different abstraction levels from software transactions (a frame of data) to the individual pin wiggles. These layers are very similar to [OSI Network Model](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/layers-of-osi-model/). Layering also help with maintenance and reusability by defining clear interfaces that enable you to build up a larger system. It's hard to see the benefits of this on a testbench for a small combinational block.

Parallelism come into play for other reasons. There are relatively few complete designs out there that can be tested as a single stream of inputs and then comparing the output to a reference model. You might be able to test one small block of a design this way, but not a complete chip as it typically has many interfaces that need to be driven in parallel.

But let's take the case of two simple blocks that you tested individually with the approach above. Now you want to connect them together where the output of the first DUT becomes the driver of the second DUT

Driver1 -> DUT1 -> DUT2 -> Monitor2

This works best if I originally write the drivers and monitors as separate objects running in parallel.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The last bit confused me. If we take the example of two DUTs, we can reuse the driver written for Dut 1 and write only monitor2. The TB written for DUT1 may be sequential or parallel. How does it explain that the blocks should be run in parallel?

Comment: Also, I do understand that when there is a chip with multiple interfaces, you may want individual testbench environments for those interfaces to run in parallel. For that, we can just fork-join those different environment runs. But, why do we need to have parallelism within one environment? Is this because in this way, each block of the layered testbench is more reusable, i.e. can be detached and attached to a new DUT env. easily? In each environment, only monitor and driver are running in parallel, not other blocks.